# Reusable permission checking for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-permissions

Adding the following block of code is too verbos to have in every function

```kotlin
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        context,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
) {
    return
}
```

I can write a function to either early quit or takes a block and execute it if a certian permission is present.

But android studio couldn't infrence that I'm safe, how can I mark that?

I tried to make a function that takes a block and execute it if permissions are granted

```kotlin
private inline fun withBluetoothScan(context: Context, block: () -> Unit) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        block()
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to have some annotation to tell android studio that inside this function we can use the functionality that requires this permission.

Something like:

```kotlin
@Safe(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
private inline fun withBluetoothScan(context: Context, block: () -> Unit) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        block()
    }
}
```

We have the `@Suppress("MissingPermission")` but I'm searching for something silence android studio only inside this block or after calling a function that returns early.

Answer (score 0):

There is an annotation [RequiresPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/RequiresPermission):

```kotlin
    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
```

Comment: RequiresPermission marks a function as it can't be used, so android studio gives lint errors on usage unless we provide it in the manifest and have checks for the permission.

Comment: I'm looking at how we can make it reusable and clean, we can use Suppress, but it's not clean as it will suppress all missing permissions :/